# bounce after collision doesnt work and object clips through terrain

Tags: processing, game-physics, collision

**EDIT** I changed my code to the one below but it still clips through the terrain sometimes. It also likes to bounce on corners where it should slide off. 
I tried implementing my own collision for a little game I am making. This is the code for my ball class.

```
class Ball {
  //config
  float gforce = 1;
  float friction = 0.8;
  float elasticity = 0.5;
  //vars
  PVector position;
  PVector velocity = new PVector(0, 0);

  Ball(PVector p) {position = p;}

  void render(){fill(255, 255, 0); noStroke(); circle(position.x, height-position.y, 16);}

  PVector bounce(PVector v, PVector n){  //calculate velocity after bounce
    PVector u = PVector.mult(n,v.dot(n)/n.dot(n));
    PVector w = PVector.sub(v, u);
    return PVector.sub(PVector.mult(w, friction), PVector.mult(u, elasticity));
  }
  Boolean intersect(PVector c, PVector p1, PVector p2, float r){
    if (c.dist(p1)<=r || c.dist(p2)<=r){return true;}
    float len = p1.dist(p2);
    float dot = ( ((c.x-p1.x)*(p2.x-p1.x)) + ((c.y-p1.y)*(p2.y-p1.y)) )/(len*len);
    PVector closest = PVector.add(p1, PVector.mult(PVector.sub(p2, p1), dot));
    float d1 = closest.dist(p1);
    float d2 = closest.dist(p2);
    if (d1+d2>=len-0.1 && d1+d2<=len+0.1){if(closest.dist(c)<=r){return true;}}
    return false;
  }
  Boolean intersect(PVector p1, PVector p2, PVector p3, PVector p4){  //if the line p1p2 intersects line p3p4
    float uA = ((p4.x-p3.x)*(p1.y-p3.y) - (p4.y-p3.y)*(p1.x-p3.x))/((p4.y-p3.y)*(p2.x-p1.x) - (p4.x-p3.x)*(p2.y-p1.y));
    float uB = ((p2.x-p1.x)*(p1.y-p3.y) - (p2.y-p1.y)*(p1.x-p3.x))/((p4.y-p3.y)*(p2.x-p1.x) - (p4.x-p3.x)*(p2.y-p1.y));
    if (uA>=0 && uA<=1 && uB>=0 && uB<=1){return true;}else{return false;}
  }

  void moveBall(){
    //if the ball is stationary
    if(velocity.mag()==0 || velocity.mag()==1 || velocity.mag()==2){
      PVector v = new PVector(min(280, max(-280, mX-mouseX)), min(280, max(-280, mouseY-mY))).div(28);
      int n = int(max(abs(v.x), abs(v.y)));
      v.normalize().mult(25);
      //render arrow
      if(mX!=0 && mousePressed){
        strokeWeight(5); stroke(#75D5FD); line(mX, mY, mouseX, mouseY);
        for (int i=0; i<n+1; i++){
          noStroke(); fill(510*(float)i/12, 510*(1-(float)i/12), 0, 55+200*(1-(float)i/12)); circle(mX+(v.x*i), mY-(v.y*i), 15);
        }
      }
      if(mX==0 && mouseP){mX=mouseX; mY=mouseY; mouseP=false;} 
      if(mX!=0 && mouseR){b.velocity = new PVector(min(280, max(-280, mX-mouseX)), min(280, max(-280, mouseY-mY))).div(8); mX=0; mouseR=false;}  //apply velocity
    }else {
      //if the ball is still, do not allow additional movement
      if(mX!=0 && mousePressed){stroke(200); line(mX, mY, mouseX, mouseY);}
      if(mX==0 && mouseP){mX=mouseX; mY=mouseY; mouseP=false;} 
      if(mX!=0 && mouseR){mX=0; mouseR=false;}
    }
  }

  void collision(){
    //test collision with terrain
    for (int i=1; i<l.points.length; i++){
      PVector centerout = PVector.div(velocity, velocity.mag()).mult(8);
      strokeWeight(5); stroke(255,0,0); line(position.x, height-position.y, position.x+centerout.x+velocity.x, height-position.y-centerout.y-velocity.y);
      if(intersect(position, l.points[i-1], l.points[i], 7) || intersect(position, PVector.add(position,velocity,centerout), l.points[i-1], l.points[i])){
        velocity = bounce(velocity, l.normals[i-1]);
      }
    }
  }

  void move() {
    moveBall();
    collision();
    position.add(velocity);
    if(velocity.y>-10){velocity.y-=gforce;}
    if(velocity.mag()<0.5){velocity.x=0; velocity.y=0;}
  }
}
```

There is another object, l (which is the terrain), and it stores the array points[] which contains all the coordinates for the terrain. There is a line connecting each point and the ball detects if its velocity vector intersects that line, or if the ball itself intersects that line.

When i drag and release my mouse, it changes the velocity to whatever vector the mouse was dragged in. It then detects for a collision and it changes the velocity based on its current velocity and the normal of the terrain. However, when it does that, it flies in the opposite direction and flings itself through the floor.

How can I fix my code so that the collision and bouncing works as expected? Additionally it will be nice if the velocity eventually became 0 after bouncing a while.

Oh and usually the y position goes up the further you go down but I changed it so that the y position goes down the further you go down. SO at the very bottom, the y position is 0 instead of the height of the canvas.

Comment: You seem to be calculating the collision _when the ball intersects_. That may be part of the problem. Once the ball is _inside_ the object with which it collides, if the new vector doesn't get it out of it in 1 frame you may get stuck with a collision loop. I once dealt with a similar problem in a arkanoid-like program by calculating the possibility of a collision actually _before it happens_. When a collision was foreseen that way, I split the movement so the ball wouldn't actually enter the other object but just bounce on it before it would enter it, so they never really intersected.

Comment: The new code above should solve that problem. It still clips through though when I get really close to a corner and bounce into the corner.

Comment: The new vector may be the issue here. If there's no clipping with the normal movements, but no validation on the new vector, it may result in this problem. BTW congrats on this improvement!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see the problem now but I don't know how I would go about fixing it since the program will have to look infinitely forward if the new bounce velocity collides and if the bounce velocity of that velocity collides and so on? Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your current problem, <strike>I actually have 2 different suggestions</strike> *I decided to offer only the first one after consideration, as the second one can throw you into recursive madness, but I'm willing to expand on it if needed*. I cannot really test them or offer you real code without a working example, though, so I'll stay on pseudocode level.

### Solution 1: easy and robust

This one is pretty straightforward: save the pre-bounce vector. When the ball actually bounce, if the rebound has clipping, forget about it and inverse the initial vector. Since the ball came from this exact direction, you can be pretty damn sure that it can go back that way.

The algo would go like this:

```
if ValidateMove(CurrentVector):
  Move(CurrentVector)
else:
  NewVector = CalculateNewVector
  if ValidateMove(NewVector):
    Move(NewVector)
  else:
    Move(CurrentVector.Invert)
```

There's a possible problematic edge case, though. If another object is in movement, it may block the ball's inverted path. Honestly, I wouldn't care about the chance that this happens unless your game is specifically prone to this.

Hope this'll help!

Comment: Thanks, I tried it out but the problem still persists. I’ve tried slowing the framerate down and seeing frame by frame but I have no idea why it just clips. Should I send my entire code once I get home?

Comment: Sure, I'll see if I can help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! I’m still not home but this is my code. https://pastebin.com/Eb97txY4. I don’t have the level file right now but if you save the following under /LevelEditor/levels.dat and change currentlevel in the code to 0, it should load: 100,200:800,800:0,150,300,150,300,100,350,100,350,150,500,20,500,150,600,150,700,300::::

Comment: I got it working. Instead of reversing the vector I simply set the velocity to 0 since it will eventually be 0 after bouncing over and over again. That seemed to fix the clipping issue. There are some other issues but ill fix that later

Comment: I like how you just jumped over this instead of going into the recalculation rabbit hole. Good thinking!

Comment: Hey I know it’s been a while but would something like this work? If abs(velocity)<0.1 {velocity=0 }Else {Velocity += gravity } If collision {Position = collision point, Velocity = bounce(velocity) }Else {Position+=velocity}

Comment: It's good thinking. I would need context for full appraisal, but in theory it's a clever way to deal with the issue. I don't know if it can happen, but what if the bounce takes the ball into another collision, like near a corner?

Comment: In theory it should just continuously teleport the ball to the corner. I’ll try it out and see if it works

Comment: @Orbital Thanks for updating me! I'm glad it did.